# How to increase DatePicker height in ipad?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

How do I increase DatePicker height in iPad? Is this possible? And also one more doubt is, is it possible to increase the UITableView vertical scrollbar is more visible? (i.e I want to increase the vertical scrollbar width).

Every time I load the tableview data, the first time the scrollbar is not visible.  When I drag the tableview only it shows the vertical scroll bar.  I want to set vertical scrollbar as default when I load my tableview data.

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of picker views are fixed. This is necessary to create the optical illusion that makes them work.

I don't think that the scroll indicator can be activated until a scroll is attempted but I'm not certain about that.